# Open set of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $\lambda\to F(\lambda)$  a family of  meromorphic functions on an open set $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\mu\in \mathbb{C}$.

Put $U_\mu=\{\lambda\in \Omega: \mu$  is not a pole of   $ F(\lambda)   \}$.

My question: is $U_\mu$ an open set of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $C$ is $\mathbb{C}$ or Cantor set.?

Answer (score 1):

No, not without further restrictions. Right now there is absolutely no condition on how this family depends on $\lambda$.

For example let $F(\lambda)(z)=\begin{cases}\frac1z &\lambda\neq0\\z&\lambda=0\end{cases}$ , then $U_0=\{0\}$ is not open.